# how to solve error ModuleNotFoundError on virtual env subdirectory?

Tags: python, import, python-venv, standard-library

As seen in the image below, I finished working on my project folder "click" under the main folder "my project." I didn't establish a virtual environment when I first started working on the project, but after I finished it, I did so and imported all of the packages that the files in the "click" folder required (and deleted all packages in the global environment).

The issue is that when I execute any project file in the "click" folder, I receive an error message that says `"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named'module name'."` The packages I installed when I built the virtual environment folder "my project" appear to be invisible to the subdirectory.

Can someone tell me what I need to do in order to solve this problem?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Have you activated the Virtual Environment?

Navigate to the top-folder of your directory and run run

```sh
.\venv\Scripts\activate
```

(assuming you used [`virtualenv`](https://mothergeo-py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/development/how-to/venv-win.html)).

After this, all local packages should become available.